# JavaFx. Изменение стиля TreeItem по условию

Tags: java, css, javafx

Имеется дерево, каждый элемент которого наследует интерфейс Viewable:

```
public interface Viewable {

    enum ViewStyle {

        NEW("-fx-background-color: b8faa7;"),
        NEW_PARENT("-fx-background-color: b8ebbb;"),
        LOCKED("-fx-background-color: adadad; "),
        HAS_NO_DATA("-fx-background-color: eb8d8d;");

        String style;

        ViewStyle(String style){
            this.style = style;
        }

        public String getStyle() {
            return style;
        }

    }

    ViewStyle getViewStyle();
    void setViewStyle(ViewStyle style);
    StringProperty styleProperty();

    String getTreeItemTitle();
    void setTreeItemTitle(String title);
    StringProperty titleProperty();

}
```

Каждый объект имеет свой `styleProperty()`, значение берет из `ViewStyle.getStyle()`

В самом дереве к каждой TreeCell "биндится" данное свойство:

```
treeView.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<Viewable>, TreeCell<Viewable>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeCell<Viewable> call(TreeView<Viewable> param) {
                return new TreeCell<Viewable>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Viewable item, boolean empty) {
                        textProperty().unbind();
                        styleProperty().unbind();
                        if (empty || item == null) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                            textProperty().set(null);
                            styleProperty().set(null);
                        }
                        if (item != null) {
                            styleProperty().bind(item.styleProperty());
                            textProperty().bind(item.titleProperty());
                        }
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

Проблема в том, что некрасиво отображаются строки дерева при выделении. Т.е. цвет выделенной ячейки не меняется. Понять, что ячейка выделена можно только по изменению цвета букв, а это очень не удобно. По сему, видимо придется пристраивать `.css` файлы. При этом не понятно, как менять стиль ячейки в зависимости от текущего `ViewStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на вашем месте действительно сделал через css и классы, а не стили.

Примерно следующее

.css файл

```
.new {
 -fx-background-color : red;
 другие свойства
}

.newParent {

}

.locked {

}

.hasNoData {

}
```

Viewable.ViewStyle

```
enum ViewStyle {
    NEW("new"),
    NEW_PARENT("newParent"),
    LOCKED("locked"),
    HAS_NO_DATA("hasNoData");
    String style;
    ViewStyle(String style) {
        this.style = style;
    }
    public String getStyle() {
        return style;
    }
}
```

и в фэктори написал бы следующее

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Viewable item, boolean empty) {
    textProperty().unbind();
    getStyleClass().removeAll(Arrays.toList(Viewable.ViewStyle.values()));
    if (empty || item == null) {
        setGraphic(null);
        textProperty().set(null);
        return;
    }
    if (item != null) {
        getStyleClass().addAll(item.getViewStyle().getStyle());
        textProperty().bind(item.titleProperty());
    }
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
}
```

Comment: Все таки я не уверен в правильности решения, т.к. `updateItem() ` вызывается при изменении дерева. Т.е. допустим, в параллельном потоке обрабатывается информация, и меняются значения `ViewStyle`. Разве это будет в реальном времени меняться, или придется каждый раз перестраивать дерево?

Comment: Верно, получается что не будет. Попробуйте тогда  на styleClassProperty завязаться.

Comment: т.е. по принципу как в коде вопроса к styleProperty()?

Comment: Абсолютно верно